# Music on YouTube? Isn't it a copyright violation?

Tags: intellectual-property

How is it that people can post musical soundtracks and pop songs on YouTube? Doesn't that violate copyright laws?

Comment: Robbing banks? Isn't it a crime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does.

Youtube has a service where copyright owners of music can monetize infringing videos such that ad revenue goes to the copyright holder rather than the uploader.

Alternatively the copyright holder can choose to have the video stripped of the music or taken down.

In all other cases, the copyright owner simply isnt bothered to employ people to find illegally uploaded copies of the music

Comment: Although, in a number of cases (generally less-known artists) the poster is the rights-holder.

Comment: @user6726 It's also far from uncommon to see official music videos posted by the rights holder (or with their permission).